# How to append a canvas with large width scaled down so the page width doesn't get large

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to append a big canvas (width=2000) into dom, and scale it down so it fits the viewport. But then the page size get's unnecessarily big. How can I avoid the page size getting big while having a big canvas scaled down.

```js
function addCanvas(element) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  
  canvas.width = 2000;
  canvas.height = 2000;
  
  canvas.style.transform = 'scale(0.2)';
  
  element.append(canvas);
}

addCanvas(document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
#app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}

#app canvas {
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve this https://jackrugile.com/mono-move/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think the Code below is excactly what you wanted, I just added

```
 max-width: 100vw;
 max-height: 100vh;
```

and removed your scaling, and added the conventional resets.

```js
function addCanvas(element) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  
  canvas.width = 2000;
  canvas.height = 2000;
  
  element.append(canvas);
}

addCanvas(document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#app {
  background: #ccc;
  /* Solution for additional Comment */
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#app canvas {
  background: red;
  /* Solution */
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
</div>
```